# PHP saving imagecreatefrompng

Tags: php, save, php-gd

I want to save my pngs, but my code does not allow me to create new pngs or overwrite the existing ones. Ideally every time the page is loaded the image would be saved.

```
<?php
$width = 640;
    $height = 480;  
    $font = 23;

    $string = "This is my text";
    $im = @imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagesavealpha($im, true);
    imagealphablending($im, false);
    $white = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    imagefill($im, 0, 0, $white);
    $lime = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 51);
    imagettftext($im, $font, 0, 0, $font - 3, $lime, "./DroidSerif-Bold.ttf", $string);
    $im = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");
    imagedestroy($im);



?>
```

Comment: `imagecreatefrompng` doesn't *save* an image, it *loads* one...

Comment: Define `but my code does not allow me to create new pngs or overwrite the existing ones`. In what way does your code not allow that? Also you need to use `imagepng` to create a new png file. `imagecreatefrompng` creates a new image object in PHP to manipulate.

Answer (score 4):

`imagecreateFROMpng` as it names indicates creates an image object by reading a `.PNG` file. In order to save the image as a PNG, you must use the `imagepng` [function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php):

```
...
imagettftext($im, $font, 0, 0, $font - 3, $lime, "./DroidSerif-Bold.ttf", $string);
imagepng($im, "test.png");
imagedestroy($im);
```